# When should a politician be referred to by their most senior held position, as opposed to strictly their current one?

Tags: united-states, terminology

Sometimes current/former politicians are referred to by their **most senior held** (previous or current) title,  rather than *strictly* their *current* title.

For example, in a 2016 Presidential debate, Hillary Clinton was referred to as 'secretary', even though her role of secretary of state ceased 3 years' prior in [Feb 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Secretaries_of_State_of_the_United_States).

Another example is Barack Obama's current [medium profile](https://medium.com/@barackobama) stating 'President'.

[image]

When does the convention of referring to a politician by their most senior held title (rather than strictly their *current* title only) apply? It contrasts somewhat to some other professions like medicine or finance, where referring to oneself by a previous position can be viewed as inaccurate (e.g. as a doctor or financial planner respectively, if one does not **currently** hold the said position).

Comment: She didn't hold any office when she was running in 2016 from what I remember.

Comment: @JoeW I agree. So why the title 'secretary'? (perhaps a tacit shortcut for 'former secretary', for everyone's convenience)

Comment: Note that this convention is country-specific. In the UK, for example, politicians are only referred to by their current titles, not their previous ones. There is only ever one person at at a time addressed as "Prime Minister", for example.

Comment: As an interesting side note: In Germany, ex chancellors retain their title of *Bundeskanzler* but with the initials *a.D.* (meaning *außer Dienst* or *out of office*). It is common to refer to them as *Altbundeskanzler* (literally *old Federal Chancellor*) but that is not an official title or address and they remain addressed as *Herr Bundeskanzler*, sometimes with an explicit *a.D.* (currently this only applies to Schröder). For mayors (*Bürgermeister*), a similar term *Altbürgermeister* exists, *but* this is a formal title the town council awards to a mayor leaving office if they so desire.

Comment: So my hometown’s former mayor Schnitzer is *Herr Altbürgermeister Schnitzer* while ex-chancellor Schröder is *Herr Bundeskanzler (a.D.) Schröder.*

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff note that in the UK, "Prime Minister" is not used as a personal title (like "Lord") but as the customary name of a cabinet office.  So you should not say "Prime Minister Johnson" but "The Prime Minister" or "Mr Johnson". (or "the right honorable gentleman, member for Uxbridge and South Ruislip")

Comment: @James K, as I recall, “Mr/Mrs” was always the way the PM was addressed until Blair came along with his obsession of being a presidential figure and insisted on being addressed as “Prime Minister”.

Comment: This is currently asking multiple questions, please [edit] it so that it is only asking one question.

Comment: What "current position" did Obama or Clinton have in your examples?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it is strictly a question of etiquette and protocol. It does not have a justiciable answer that a court could resolve.

Custom and practice would be to always refer to someone by their current title if they currently hold elective or judicial office, and to otherwise refer to someone by their highest title when there is an intent to recognize their prior service as a civil servant or elected official.

There are also standards of etiquette and precedent for which previously held posts are illustrious enough to call for recognition at all. Federal district court judge or Senator or President, yes. Dog catcher, or gymnastics judge or president of the intramural soccer club, not so much.

A good rule of thumb would be that a former title is normally recognized for anyone who would have been addressed "Honorable" while holding the office.

More specific and possibly legally meaningful standards apply to former military officers, but I'm not familiar with those standards.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the current etiquette of referring to former office holders by their former titles is fairly recent.  Etiquette books I've seen from 50 or 60 years ago proscribe the practice.

Comment: I've seen the practice in literary accounts (admittedly fictional but a product of their time) going back a couple of hundred years. There may have been a brief movement to end the practice that floundered.

Comment: Sounds like a great follow up question for History.SE